# Как понять это литерал или это унарный минус?

Tags: c++

```
int x = -1;
```

`-` в этом случае это часть литерала или это унарный оператор?

Comment: в чем причина такого вопроса? думаю, с точки зрения ast это cкорее всего унарный оператор

Comment: [Integer literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal). There are no negative integer literals. Expressions such as -1 apply the unary minus operator to the value represented by the literal. - Отрицательных целых литералов не существует. Такие выражения, как -1, применяют унарный оператор минус к значению, представленному литералом.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, надо было ответом :)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Интересно, а как трактуется что-то типа `-2147483648`? Как литерал с переполнением, к которому потом применяется унарный минус?...

Comment: @Harry Раз не влезает в `int`, то это [`long`] `long`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Integer literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal).

Цитата:
There are no negative integer literals. Expressions such as `-1` apply the unary minus operator to the value represented by the literal.

Перевод:
Отрицательных целых литералов не существует. Такие выражения, как `-1`, применяют унарный оператор минус к значению, представленному литералом.